# Twilio international SMS not sending

Tags: twilio

I've bought a UK number. I'm trying to send SMS myself (a USA based number). It doesn't work. I've checked off all the countries in "Messaging Geographic Permissions". Still it doesn't work. The USA based number I've bought DOES work. All the documentation on Twilio's website alludes to international SMS working for UK based numbers.

Comment: Do you have a mobile (starting with +447) or landline UK number (starting with +441)? Do you get an error message from the API when you try to send the message?

Comment: I have a +44 77** ****** number

Comment: And do you get an error message from the API call?

Comment: RestException [Error]: The From phone number ++44 77** ****** is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account.

Comment: The numbers says CAPABILITIES: Voice, Fax, SMS

Comment: Are you formatting the number correctly when using the UK number? It should be +4477******** with no spaces or other punctuation.

Comment: I was just able to send an international SMS (from UK to Australia) from my account. Other things to check, are you trying to send to a landline number? Are you using your real credentials or are you using test credentials? If all of this still doesn't help, I recommend contacting [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and let them know what is going on so that they can investigate.

Comment: I'm using it with spaces. Checking now without spaces..

Comment: How did that go?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228779/discussion-between-gn-and-philnash).